# C# string was not recognized as a valid DateTime in Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, string

I am working on C# .net, i want to insert a date time which is of 12 chunk. Bellow is my code

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occurrence_Time", Convert.ToDateTime(Meter_data.Substring(161, 12)));
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recovery_Time", Convert.ToDateTime(Meter_data.Substring(173, 12)));
```

While running my program i'am getting the following error

```
string was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

Using **Quick Watch** the date time is like `161025120830`and while inserting it the date time should be like `2016-10-25 12:08:30`

In above line the date starts with `16` but in Database it should be inserted as 2016

**Updated Code**

As suggested by `un-lucky`, I have made the following changes to the code, See bellow

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_ID", device_Id);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Energy_kWh", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(18, 9)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Power_kW", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(144, 7)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voltage_Phase_1", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(102, 6)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voltage_Phase_2", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(109, 6)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Voltage_Phase_3", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(116, 6)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Current_Phase_1", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(123, 6)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Current_Phase_2", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(130, 6)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Current_Phase_3", Convert.ToDecimal(Meter_data.Substring(137, 6)));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_Serial_Number", Meter_data.Substring(152, 8));

    //For Events


    string formatString = "yyMMddHHmmss";
    DateTime Occurrence_Time, Recovery_Time;
    string strOccurrence = Meter_data.Substring(161, 12);
    string strRecovery = Meter_data.Substring(173, 12);


    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device_ID", device_Id);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event_ID", event_Id);

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time))
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time))
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Occurrence_Time;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Recovery_Time;
        }
    }



    //cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occurrence_Time", Convert.ToDateTime(Meter_data.Substring(161, 12)));
    //cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recovery_Time", Convert.ToDateTime(Meter_data.Substring(173, 12)));

    int ADS_Device_Data_rows_executed = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Rows Executed: '{0}'", ADS_Device_Data_rows_executed);

    int Device_Events_rows_executed = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Rows Executed: '{0}'", Device_Events_rows_executed);
    con.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Recieved correctly and Stored in Data Base : {0}", DateTime.Now);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Data Recieved is Incorrect Data is not stored in DB : {0}", DateTime.Now);
}
```

While debugging when the pointer comes at `if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time))`

It doesn't goes in it and gives the exception `Must declare the scalar variable "@Occurrence_Time".`

Moreover there may be more than one **Occurrence Time** and **Recover Time**, but for now it's just for one event time

I have searched many articles on this exception but couldn't find any accurate solution for `Parameters.AddWithValue`

**Updated Code 2**

Following a suggestion i have done the following changes in my code

```
        string formatString = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
        DateTime Occurrence_Time ,Recovery_Time;
        string strOccurrence = "20" + Meter_data.Substring(161, 12);
        string strRecovery = "20" + Meter_data.Substring(173, 12);

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Occurrence_Time))
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out Recovery_Time))
                {
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Occurrence_Time;
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Recovery_Time;
                }
            }
```

At first run i was able to view correct data and inserted it successfuly, but now it's showing me empty see the picture bellow

[image]

Now again i am getting the same exception

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@Occurrence_Time".
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: "and while inserting it the date time should be like" - no, when inserting it should be a `DateTime`. That's fine, because you *are* converting to a `DateTime`. But you should use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify the format that you expect, which appears to be `yyMMddHHmmss`. The conversion to `DateTime` is completely separate from the fact that you happen to be using it in `AddWithValue`. (As an aside, I'd suggest not using `AddWithValue` at all... specify the type and then set the value.)

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @JonSkeet my query for inserting data into **event** table is `SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Device_Events (Device_ID, Event_ID, Occurrence_Time, Recovery_Time) values (@Device_ID , @Event_ID, @Occurrence_Time, @Recovery_Time)", con);`

Comment: I'm not sure how that comment is relevant... but please pay more attention when adding code to a post. Make sure it's indented just enough, but no further than required.

Comment: Next, reduce it to a [mcve]. The majority of the code you've presented is irrelevant to the question of how to parse a date/time string in the format you want.

Comment: What is the value of `strOccurrence` when it cannot be parsed? Are you sure that string is always a correct date?

Comment: @HansKesting actually i am getting data from meter and all the data including date time is correct yes

Comment: @fasi - apparently the data is *not* correct, as TryParse returns a `false`. So what *is* that date-string?

Comment: @HansKesting date time string is `161025120830`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your Date/Time parsing, not the insertion.  So you just need to provide the date time format as follows:

```
string formatString = "yyMMddHHmmss";
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out dt))
```

Comment: OP beware of two things, this will `boolean`, which you use to Add parameter and as Jon suggested, preferably don't use `AddWithValue`, supply the type explicitly

Comment: After adding `cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occurrence_Time", DateTime.ParseExact(Meter_data.Substring(161, 12),format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` i am getting same error, while in **format** i have   `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` also in your answer it is `yyMMddHHmmss` but i want the year to be **2016** not just **16**

Comment: @fasi - you're specifying the format of the *string* you're passing in. Your string doesn't have a 4 digit year, nor does it contain dashes, colons or spaces. So your `format` is definitely incorrect. Once the data is converted into a `DateTime`, it doesn't *have* a format (internally, it's a count of the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since midnight at the start of 01/01/0001)

Comment: @fasi You just need to set the formatString to match the actual values that you are providing - the example I gave matches that which I state in your question as being shown in the QuickWatch window.  More information on custom format strings is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

So the input for convert function is `161025120830`, and we can say that this will be in the format of  `yyMMddHHmmss` So the best option for you to do this conversion is `DateTime.TryParseExact`, convert it and stored it in a variable and then use it for insertion. The code will be like this:

```
string formatString= "yyMMddHHmmss";
DateTime Occurrence_Time,Recovery_Time;
string strOccurrence = Meter_data.Substring(161, 12);
string strRecovery = Meter_data.Substring(173, 12);

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strOccurrence,formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out Occurrence_Time))
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strRecovery,formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out Recovery_Time))
    {
      cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Occurrence_Time",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=Occurrence_Time;
      cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Recovery_Time",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=Recovery_Time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your way but getting this exception `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: 2 digits year can be ambiguous. Would you try to add `"20"` in the beginning of `strOccurence` and Parse it with `formatString = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"`

Comment: @kurakura88 i followed your way and on 1st run i successfully inserted the data, but now i am not getting correct data in `Meter_data.Substring(161, 12)` it's showing me `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`, also i appended "20" with my string but i am now unable to do it as date is not coming correctly, kindly see the updated code

Comment: the problem is that you have unexpected input source. What do you want to do with it? 1. Ignore the malformed input? 2. Insert with default time? 3. Fix the original source Meter_data to have proper date.